# grid - Trouble with making text stick to the left

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a responsive webpage where I need an image to stick to the right, and text stick to the left on large screens then make the image stay on top of the text on small screens. I tried using css grid and it worked for the image, but for some reason, the text doesn't start at the leftmost part of the grid.

It looks like this:

[image]

I've included the relevant part of my code below.

```css
    container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        /*padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;*/
    }

    .row {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 20px;
        background-color: powderblue;
    }

    .col-lg-right-4 {
        grid-column: col-start 9 / span 4
    }

    .col-lg-left-6 {
        grid-column: col-start / span 6;
        grid-row: 1;
    }

    .col-md-right-4 {
        grid-column: col-start 9 / span 4
    }

    .col-md-left-6 {
        grid-column: col-start / span 6;
        grid-row: 1;
    }

    .col-xs-12 {
        grid-column: span 12;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-right-4 col-md-right-4 col-xs-12">
                <img src="assets/svg/asset-board_one-planet.svg" id="one-planet" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-left-6 col-md-left-6 col-xs-12">
                <h3><b>WHAT</b> is This Title</h3>
                <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec neque et ipsum cursus aliquet. Ut tristique quis tortor eu consectetur. Nunc semper in neque egestas hendrerit. Aliquam congue ex id ex suscipit viverra. Ut pulvinar erat eu turpis eleifend imperdiet. Integer sodales id eros et fermentum. Ut iaculis neque sapien, id mollis ligula pretium ultricies.
                        Nunc a convallis lectus. Quisque elementum neque non ligula semper lobortis. Nulla nec turpis dictum, tincidunt massa sit amet, viverra erat. Quisque sit amet pretium orci. Duis egestas odio ac nisi mattis blandit. Etiam maximus quam sollicitudin, aliquam nisl at, convallis lacus. Nam eget suscipit ligula. Aliquam quis mi a odio posuere hendrerit. Curabitur et posuere nibh.</p>
            </div>

            
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you specify the grid layout elsewhere in your stylesheet - if so, can you add it in to the code? I've edited your post to use a code snippet https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines

Comment: Well no, that's the only place where I defined a grid layout. But I do use a flex layout in other parts, does that count?

Comment: in order for the code snippet widget to work, you will need to add the grid layout to the CSS

Comment: see the link I put above, there's some extra stuff you need to do to make the grid layout work

Comment: Thanks! I checked it, but I already defined the grid layout. If I remember correctly, I don't really need to put names for the grid columns

Comment: great, can you put them in the code snippet above, then, so that it works as a test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [main-start] 1fr [content-start] 1fr [content-end] 1fr [main-end];
  grid-template-rows: [main-start] 100px [content-start] 100px [content-end] 100px [main-end];
}

.box1 {
    grid-column-start: main-start;
    grid-row-start: main-start;
    grid-row-end: main-end;
 }

.box2 {
  grid-column-start: content-end;
  grid-row-start: main-start;
  grid-row-end: content-end;
}

.box3 {
  grid-column-start: content-start;
  grid-row-start: main-start;
}

.box4 {
  grid-column-start: content-start;
  grid-column-end: main-end;
  grid-row-start: content-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
       
            <div class="box1">
                <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/globe-icon_23-2147508246.jpg" width="200" height="200" id="one-planet" />
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                <h3><b>WHAT</b> is This Title</h3>
                <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec neque et ipsum cursus aliquet. Ut tristique quis tortor eu consectetur. Nunc semper in neque egestas hendrerit. Aliquam congue ex id ex suscipit viverra. Ut pulvinar erat eu turpis eleifend imperdiet. Integer sodales id eros et fermentum. Ut iaculis neque sapien, id mollis ligula pretium ultricies.
                        Nunc a convallis lectus. Quisque elementum neque non ligula semper lobortis. Nulla nec turpis dictum, tincidunt massa sit amet, viverra erat. Quisque sit amet pretium orci. Duis egestas odio ac nisi mattis blandit. Etiam maximus quam sollicitudin, aliquam nisl at, convallis lacus. Nam eget suscipit ligula. Aliquam quis mi a odio posuere hendrerit. Curabitur et posuere nibh.</p>
            </div>

            
        </div>
```